# Add post class to the TinyMCE iframe?

Tags: php, tinymce, iframe, body-class

I want to add styles to `editor-style.css`, based on the category the current post belongs to.

Therefore I would like to add the post classes - using `get_post_class()` - to the body of the TinyMCE iframe.

I've seen [this question](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-add-class-to-iframe-body-of-tinymce-for-specific-content-styling), but it's about adding classes via JavaScript, and I need it to be done via PHP so I can use `get_post_class()`. Neither can I use the `admin_body_class` filter, because that doesn't address the TinyMCE iframe.

How can I add the post's classes to the TinyMCE iframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The filter you're after is `tiny_mce_before_init`. Using this, we can hook into TinyMCE's 'init_array' and add body classes:

```
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'wpse_235194_tiny_mce_classes' );

function wpse_235194_tiny_mce_classes( $init_array ){

  global $post;

  if( is_a( $post, 'WP_Post' ) ){
    $init_array['body_class'] .= ' ' . join( ' ', get_post_class( '', $post->ID ) );
  }

  return $init_array;

}
```

We're joining the post classes with a space to convert them from an array to a string as required by TinyMCE, and we're also checking that we do actually have a valid post object, to avoid errors if you're using TinyMCE elsewhere (such as in widgets or the like).